# Integrating SIP Client (Softphone) as an ActiveX Control on a web-page

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, activex, sip

looking for a basic **SIP Client that is to be integrated as an ActiveX control** in my website. I'm aware of some like *Ozeki*, but this SIP client MUST BE:

- audio-call only; no video-call required
- need *SIP_Username*, *SIP_Password*, *SIP_Proxy*, *SIP_Port* *(No STUN/TURN credentials required)* to connect to my ***Asterisk Server***
- free & open-source
- call recording a bonus feature, but not mandatory

I'm aware of the fact that this approach has many loopholes in it, and shouldn't be encouraged, but these are least of my concerns for now. **I just need to connect to a SIP Server from my web-page without using WebRTC or any such dependency.** Your suggestions and recommendations *(for a smarter approach)* would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IE is the single browser where ActiveX can be used nowadays.
I would recommend to search for a java applet webphone as that can be run also from Firefox. There are both free and paid solutions for this.